# What does invalid option mean when I do a git push?

Tags: git, gitosis

I have set up my own git server with gitosis. It seems to be functioning correctly but  when I do a git push I get an error message

```
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 388 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
: invalid optione: line 2: set: -
set: usage: set [--abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [arg ...]
To ssh://git@mytestserver/~/repositories/gitosis-admin.git
```

A subsequent pull does however work and seems to correctly merge.

Ideas?

Comment: Is that really a pull? (That "To" on the last line doesn't make much sense.) As for the answer, that's strange - the "invalid optione" line isn't prefixed by "remote: ", so it would seem to be on *your* end. I do know that `git pull` is implemented as a shell script, so this could be happening within it. What version of `git` are you using?

Comment: Check your .git/config file for any invalid options

Comment: That was a push...sorry my typo. Client is 1.6.5.1

Comment: @Jefromi - on a 1.7.4 client it does have remote: as a prefix

Comment: What OS do you have? What is the version of git and bash on your client machine?

Comment: Server is Windows 2008, client XP. Tried clients with 1.6.5.1 and 1.7.4. Using cygwin latest version (1.7.9 I think)

Comment: @Ian: Okay, if it's on the remote end, then it might well be a problem with your gitosis installation - which does raise the question of why you're using gitosis instead of gitolite (which is still maintained, and fuller-featured). What happens if you just `ssh git@mytestserver`?

Comment: I guess I'd not run across gitolite. Sounds like I should be using that.

Comment: In the end I used gitolite and that was much easier to set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is coming from the shell on the remote system (bash most likely).  So the login shell on the remote system is probably trying to execute a source file (like ~/.profile) that is broken.  This could also be, for example, that the user's shell is something like /bin/bash but somewhere in git or the execution path that ssh is invoking, is calling /bin/sh instead (which might be older with less options).

Comment: Thanks this answer my question. I got around it by using gitolite instead as suggest by Jefromi.